# Shell Script Input for Changing File

Tags: shell, rsync

I am writing a script for RYSNC, the script has an option that allows the user change the source file. When i run the script and enter a new source file it doesnt work and I cant figure out why. It just prints out the original ROOT even though I have entered a new different one

**Script**

```
elif [ "$opt" = "SOURCE" ]; then
echo "CURRENT DIRECTORY BEING BACKED UP: $ROOT"
echo "TO CHANGE ENTER THE NEW DESTINATION..."
echo "TO LEAVE IT AS $ROOT JUST PRESS ENTER..."
read NEW_ROOT

#IF GREATER THEN 0 ASSIGN NEW ROOT
if [ ${#NEW_ROOT} -gt 0 ];then
    $ROOT = "$NEW_ROOT"
fi
sleep 2
echo "NEW DIRECTORY: $ROOT"
clear
exit
```

Comment: Remove the spaces around the `=` in the assignment line. Also you assign to bare names so `ROOT=$NEW_ROOT`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have made the change but now when I enter in the new source the script skips the last echo and it doesnt save the new `ROOT`

Comment: The only way the last echo could be skipped is on an error. What output are you getting exactly? What do you see if you add `set -x` right after that `read NEW_ROOT` line? What do you mean "doesnt save the new `ROOT`"?

Comment: I dont know of `set -x` do i just add that line below `ROOT = "$NEW_ROOT"`? Well what I would like the script to do is change the value of ROOT if the user opts to enter a new value

Comment: Yes, just add that to your script below the `ROOT` assignment line. Then you will see debugging output of the commands that are run when the script runs. Change the value where? The assignment is only going to be in effect for the current run of the script (until that `exit` line).

Comment: When I added the `set -x` it just showed the `sleep 2` , the `echo` and then the clear. How come it is showing the echo with the 'set-x` and not showing it without it?

Comment: It seems to have fixed the error that I was having so thank you for the help

Comment: `set -x` cannot "fix" anything. You are clearing immediately after the echo. Where are you expecting to see the echoed message exactly?

Comment: no it didnt fix anything like you said I just had a `clear` in where I shouldnt have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script you are trying to set the new value wrong.
Replace

```
$ROOT = "$NEW_ROOT"
```

with this

```
ROOT = "$NEW_ROOT"
```

And that should solve it